# Convert PHP code to Android for API call

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to understand how to work with bittrex api.
It says:

For this version, we use a standard HMAC-SHA512 signing. Append apikey and nonce to your request and calculate the HMAC hash and include it under an apisign header. Note: the nonce is not respected right now but will be enforced later.

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?
apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

Can i do it without knowing PHP?
Or it's not PHP?
Or what to do with this actually?

Comment: The code you posted is PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is PHP code and I really doubt that you should execute it on your phone. You should execute it on some server and when called it will return JSON object. So your android app should call it, get JSON object, unpack it and use data from it.

Or, you can make equivalent in Java or what ever you use for coding android app and use the same technique like in this PHP example to call this bittrex api and acquire data.

Basically this code is making (I would say GET) request to bittrex api end-point. It's passing apikey and nounce so you must get real values to run it.

Then it makes sign out of api secret with PHP hash_hmac() funciton:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

So you must find some equivalent for your programming language. The it's passed as "apisign" header parameter.